# anaconda-navigator and pip install throwing (surely nested) errors

Tags: python, ssl, pip, pyqt5, anaconda3

I am currently stuck with a frustrating problem. The post is quite long because I want to be as detailed as possible.

OS: Windows 10.
Anaconda Download Version: Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64.exe

I installed anaconda according to the guidelines. However the anaconda prompt and navigator can't be found. There is a lot of troubleshooting but none of the solutions worked for me.

The closest I got was by using:

```
activate root
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all
anaconda-navigator
```

but "anaconda-navigator" got me the green circle loading screen and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 377, in _load_unsafe_channels
    new_worker.unsafe_channels = info['channels']
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 382, in _conda_info_processed
    base_worker = worker.base_worker
AttributeError: 'ProcessWorker' object has no attribute 'base_worker'
```

After closing and reopening the console I typed "anaconda-navigator" again got a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

This led me to the idea of using "pip install pyqt5" which caused error:

```
C:\Users\Moritz>pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\Moritz>pip install pyqt5
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyqt5/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

This error was also already discussed and should be solved with:
"python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip"
but this won't work at all in my case.

My system variables $PATH includes the directory to C:\Users\Moritz\anaconda3\Scripts where python is located. It also includes a java path(problematic?)

Comment: Why did you add the "Scripts" folder to the PATH during installation. Anaconda doesn't recommend doing so, since conda has a different paradigm. Did you also skip initializing your shells? Then you got what you deserved ...

Comment: @Peter I thought this might fix it. However if i remove it from the path the errors remain. What do you mean by initalizing my shells?